# Guestbook (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know how to make guestbook on sharepoint site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the survey list

Answer (score 0):

Or a custom list configured for anonymous acces would work too.  To configure anonymous access, start here:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/enable-anonymous-access-HA010113018.aspx